# To vs For difference

Tags: prepositions

Could anyone help me to understand the difference between the usage for and to in the below sentences.

> They will be more interested in the struggles of the downtrodden, in those who are fighting to obtain the title deeds for respectable humanity.

> They will be more interested in the struggles of the downtrodden, in those who are fighting to obtain the title deeds to respectable humanity.

Ideally, both the sentences are correct, however the preposition for is mostly followed by a noun whereas the preposition To is mostly followed by verbs.

So, why is "To" correct in the second sentence in comparison with the first sentence?

Comment: I don't understand what the text is supposed to mean anyway, but syntactically speaking there's also *the title deeds **of** respectable humanity* (historically, [*way*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=title+deeds+*+the+property&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) more common). I doubt the choice of preposition makes any difference as regards ambiguity over whether *[prep] **respectable humanity*** adverbially modifies ***fighting to obtain*** or adjectivally modifies ***the title deeds***, but I stand to be corrected on that.

Comment: Commonly, we get deeds **to** property, houses, things. You *could* say "I have the deed for this house right here." Also, *to* is a very popular preposition: to death, to the moon, to the end, to the bone, to year end.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: See usage chart link in my comment. The title deeds **of** property are far more common.

Comment: @FumbleFingers God bless you.

Answer (score 2):

[Cambridge defines "title deed" as:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/title-deed)

> a document that states and proves a person's legal right to own a piece of land or a building

Note that "deed" in this sense is often used with "to," as in "the deed to the house." FumbleFingers noted in the comments that historically "of" was more commonly used than "to" here, but [at the present](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=title+deeds+*+the+property&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) it appears that the two versions are both common.

So "the title deeds to respectable humanity" are the (metaphorical) documents giving someone a right to  "respectable humanity."

Presumably "respectable humanity" means something "the part of humanity that is respectable" or "being human in a way that is respectable."